# SP 2007 Workflow - Can't Locate to Modify

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Not as familiar with 2007 but I can't seem to locate workflows for an old 2007 environment. The workflows are working, but I want to make a slight modification. When I open the site with Designer07 I see no workflows. I also don't see any libraries called "Workflows" even when signed in with admin acct.

Is it possible these were created in VB and would not appear the normal way? How do I access them?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the list for the workflow.  Site workflows are based on site content type.

Comment: So when I go to list settings, and under Workflow Settings, I see the workflows listed, but when I try to click on one, I get an "Unknown Error".

Comment: In Desinger or in IE?

Comment: in IE, I can't find anything in Designer...

Comment: Try opening the list in Designer.  I didn't use it much, but I remember it being very compartmentalized.  Otherwise it might be VS.  Check your deployed solutions.

Comment: Yes Designer was what i tried first, there is nothing in there except views?

Comment: The workflows you can see in list settings >> workflow settings are probably OOTB workflows or third-party workflows which broke in an upgrade. This is the only reason I can think that you would get an error.

Comment: Also check under Site Features (at both the site and site collection levels) in case they were deployed from Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Erin. I did look under site features and I can confirm I AM seeing features there deployed that correlate by name with the workflows - so this points me to Visual Studio correct?